# Movie DB - storage of Actors / actress / Tags?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

Creating a movie db and I dont like the idea of giving each actor/actress and also each tag its own row as if there are 10 million moives total, each has a cast of atleast 20-30 people we will have 200-300 million rows in the table.

And it gets more complex with tags which can be unlimited per movie. So how to best store these 3 items? Ideally these can be modeled as a Many to Many but still it will have hundreds of millions of rows. Any better suggestions on storing these? I am using MySQL.

I would dump it all in a textfile but I need to link actors between movies and do some analytics also and allow users to rate actors find movies by tag, etc so need to use a DB.

Comment: I'd say you can't really get around many-to-many, it even sounds like the most efficient way to store this. I'm going to sit here and watch as the real DBA's enlighten us with their insights.

Comment: I think you're worrying about a problem you've not got. You have a domain that maps neatly to a relational model, where RDBMs have facilties (indexes, partitioning) that can help with performance. Build the thing along the lines of the design that all the answers are suggesting, and engage with your DBA on ways of optimising it *if* it should prove necessary

Comment: Sadly I am my own DBA! So i am learning along the way. But yes, i will try out what people have said and check the performance with a sample data set of about 10 million then post back on how it worked.

Comment: @dave how did you eventually solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

10 million movies seems pretty ambitious. [IMDb's current statistics](http://www.imdb.com/stats) show that they have less than 1.8M titles and around 3.9M people.

Having said that, I see no problem with creating a table of titles, a table of actors, and a junction table to resolve the many-to-many relationship between the two. The same holds true for tags.

[image]

Comment: IMBD is more for english movies. I am trying to build an all in 1 movie DB, all countries, all languages, all world actors from beginning of time till date. Plus this includes TV shows too.

Comment: @dave: I still think that, with proper indexing and query tuning, this design will hold up well.

Comment: Ok this may hold up for actors. I will benchmark it but what about movie tags? Those can be an open sea to map out.

Comment: +1: start with this design, and modify as needed. Horizontal paritioning aftwards, **IF** performance metrics dictate.

Comment: @dave: I'd take the same approach for tags. As @p.campbell said, start here and adjust as needed. You could always impose a reasonable limit of X tags per movie if things start to get out of hand.

Comment: I'll check it out with dummy data and see how the search works then post back. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to add the reverse indexes to query the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds perhaps a bit of [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) here. You **could** denormalize all actors into a `TEXT` column of some kind onto the Movie table, but your performance + search would suffer, as well as losing all benefits of relational data.

Suggest to keep the normalized schema, as you were originally thinking:

```
Movie (ID)
Actor (ID)
Tag (ID) --horror, comedy, etc.

MovieActor (MovieID, ActorID)
MovieTag (MovieID, TagID)
```

- Create indexes as per normal on the associative entities: `MovieActor` and `MovieTag`.
- Load some dummy data in a Test environment. 10 million movies with 100 million actors with 1 million tags. Create associative entries for each as required.
- Baseline and performance test.
- [Horizontal partitioning (sharding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) if your performance metrics require more performance.

Regardless of the number of movies, or whether the data is DNA sequences: implement a design, test it, judge its performance based on your requirements (user acceptance, SLA, etc)

Comment: MovieTag (MovieID, TagID) = 1 tag per movie? But that tag can be in many movies, so to find all movie with the given tags i need to search table by tag then?

Comment: @dave: correct. Databases are excellent at finding a given TagID when indexed properly.

Comment: sounds good, will load dummy data and check the performance, then post back.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason for your aversion to the millions of rows? A perceived performance issue?

It's going to have hundreds of millions of relations somewhere. You do have to capture the mapping between actor and film and as you say, there are 200-300  million of those (although I don't believe there are 10 million movies in existence?)

If you really wanted, you could (for example) pack the ids for actors for a film into multiple columns (or into one column) but that would make searching unpleasant.

Comment: Creating huge lookup tables. Increase search time. More rows = more data to manage. Movies are worldwide, plus includes TV shows too. I am trying to create a worldwide entertainment DB so all movies, all tv shows across the globe from start of film till date.

Comment: But the data is there (that's why I said "relation" and not row). It's inherent in the data you're working with, and you have to manage it somehow. The big "who was in what" table can be partitioned in various ways, but you're going to have to store those relationships somehow

Comment: More rows = LESS data to manage.  Each change affects only the minimal amount of data — adding a cast member involves an addition of one small row to a subsidiary table, rather than locking the movie's massive main record.  And updating the name of an actor, or his birthdate, affects only one actor row in the database.

Comment: Good point. I'll map it out and see. But what about tags? Tags for me is like a dictionary. Each word can map to any of the millions of movies, so dont tell me I need to have (X) million movies x (X) million words for storing movie tags then?

Comment: @dave: perhaps the point to you is that rows with 2 number are much much less expensive than columns are. Consider the alternative: **massively duplicated tags and actor names** in varchar columns on the Movie entity.

Comment: What queries do you need? "Movies with tag X" and "tags used by this movie". So you need to store the tag-movie relationship. However, there will be only rows for movies that actually have a given tag, so in practice it's X million movies * a small number (avg. tags per movie). The theoretical limit is #tags * #movies, but you won't get close to that in practice - no movie will have all the tags

Comment: It is similar to SO like how each Q has a tag. I was seeing SO's schema they store all 5 tags serialized in 1 row as per the schema on the net. So is that bad practice then?

Comment: If you limit the number of tags per movie, you can adopt an SO-like scheme. But in in your question you said "unlimited tags per movie" which is quite different.

Comment: In an ideal world, yes unlimited and free are what attracts users. But from the technical side it becomes more of a headache. Ok i will try to check performance with dummy data and post back.

Comment: I'd also expect caching (in the RDBMS, or in your application) to work well. Chances are that most queries/views will be of a small percentage of the films, and a few of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

10 million movies w/ 20 to 30 cast members each (although the number sound higher than real life) will invariably lead to 200-300 million associations.  If you're storing your data in a relational database, each association will naturally be one row in a table linking movies to actors.  Each row will be very small (two columns - movie PK and actor PK; possibly an extra surrogate key column); the bulk of the data will be stored in the movies and actors table.

Any other solution (in an SQL database) will store the same amount of data in a less optimal format.